# VITAL NEED: EmberJS equivalent of jQuery's .ready() function that STAYS ON

Tags: jquery, events, ember.js, event-handling

Ok. So the reason why I am labeling this as a vital need is because I have written another question like this in the past, and I gave when I was asked to give a specific thing that I was trying to accomplish, and the whole thing became about that, and nothing got solved.

Now I have come to like 5 different things I wanted to accomplish that I would've been able to accomplish with jQuery and .ready() and have ALL the functionality done in a half hour. I have spent 3 days searching Google, reading the official Ember 2.13.0 docs, etc. to no avail.

This HAS to exist, because I simply refuse to believe that I can't put an event listener that will ALWAYS run on the route regardless of transitioning to child routes or clicking things or the fact that it already rendered and doesn't render twice. The only one I've been able to get to work is `didRender` on the component. Nothing else works.

I tried willTransition on the route. Does not work. I've tried didTransition on the route. Does not work. I've searched Google only to come up with answers on here for Ember 1x.

All I want to do is have something like this:

```
Ember.$('input,select,textarea').on('change',function() {
    do stuff here
}
```

That will:

- Work when the route is entered
- Still continue to function when a user clicks on sub-routes*
- Not stop working EVER unless the user exits the actual parent route completely and goes somewhere else
- Run all the time

What `didInsertElement` on the component does is that while it's on the opening route (android/setup) .. it will actually work.. until I click a different tab that goes to a different sub route. Then it stops working and upon returning to the original sub route it starts on, it still won't work.

I don't know if it's because the component doesn't get rendered again or what but why it stops working and the event listener dies is beyond me.

I found other answers on here where people say to use `didInsertElement` .. It doesn't work for me because the event listener dies after interacting with the page. I need something that will NOT stop listening until an entirely different route off the root is picked.

If you want to know why I want to do this, I can give you 5 reasons right off the bat, so I would rather the actual EXACT PROGRAMMATIC FUNCTION I'm asking for how to do be explained instead of a single task or goal in terms of functionality because I have needed this SO MANY TIMES and have had to go around my butt to get to my elbow because I can't just .ready it and call it a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer may not be applicable everyone, but you can give it try if you want to solve your use case.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    deactivate(){
     //Here you can clear all the event handler stuff.
     Ember.$('input,select,textarea').off('change');
    },
    actions:{
        didTransition(){
            Ember.run.later('afterRender', () => {
              //this will ensure that inside this route all html element is ready,
              //Now you can whatever stuff is required to deal with html element.
              //like registering event handler. 
              Ember.$('input,select,textarea').on('change',function() {
                //  do stuff here
                }); 
            }, 500);
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Note:
1. Remember, didTransition hook should be defined in actions hash
2.It should `return true` only then it will propagate to parent route.
3.Just ensure all the child route should `return true` if in case you have written the didTransition hook.

After the route transition, whatever html content is avaliable will be triggered for `change` event. but this will not applicable for created DOM after the transition like hiding/showing component based on `if` block may not be registered for `change` event. For those stuff you need to use `didInsertElement` and `this.$('input,select').on('change', function(){})` and in willDestroyElement hook destory handler `this.$('input,select').off('change')`

Comment: I'm assuming this has to be put for each route that that part of the UI uses.. Ie. it has multiple tabs for config sections, but each section is a sub-route. So I'd have to do that for each route? What does the 500 mean? is that a delay in ms?

Comment: No. You can doing it for the parent route alone. ie., If you navigate to sub-route then its parent route `didTransition` too will be called.

Comment: Hm. okay. That makes sense and is cool. Then I would have to have the properties be in the parent route and passed down to the child component to be read by that child component.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.. the didTransition() fires for child routes like you said but the event listener/handler doesn't seem to function? I have it outputting a simple console.log and it never fires.

Comment: That should work if we schedule it in afterRender queue, if you can reproduce it in twiddle. that will be helpful to identify my misunderstanding

Comment: Also.. some people in ember community are saying it's a bad idea to use Ember.$ bc of memory leaks... So not sure what the better alternative would be but I'm thinking it should be stated here since apparently it's a thing. Do you know?

Comment: If you are inside component, then you can use `this.$` but in your case you are doing this stuff in route (which normally people avoid for doing DOM stuff) so you have no other option other than using `Ember. $`.

Comment: By the way `Ember.$` doesnt cause memory leak, if we forgot to do any cleanup related to event handler deregistering then it will lead to memory leak but other than no issue at all.

Comment: Right. Well there is a better way to do this I found out that doesn't use jQuery but I don't have time to do it now due to the poor way this app was designed. How would you do clean up on this and where?

Comment: I included that clean up part in deactivate hook. thats enough.